# How to record start and end time in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write a basic timer app that will record the time you hit start and the time you hit end and compare them. All attempts I have made so far have not printed the time, defaulting to its original definition.

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hourTime = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutesTime = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)

var TimeWhileGone=0

@IBAction func EndTime(_ sender: Any) {
    var button2Alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Your Timer have been going for \(minutesTime-TimeWhileGone) minutes!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    self.present(button2Alert, animated: true, completion: nil)*/
}

@IBAction func startTime(_ sender: Any) {
    TimeWhileGone=minutesTime
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two things, you need two points in time from which to compare, a `startTime` and a `endTime` (I know sounds simple, but you seem to have missed those points).

You seem to be recording "static" points in time which never change

So when `startTime` is called, you initialise the `startTime` property to "now" (ie `Date()`).

```
var startTime: Date?

//...
startTime = Date()
```

When `endTime` is called, you mark it and calculate the time difference, using `Date().timeIntervalSince`, which gives you a `TimeInterval`

```
guard let startTime = startTime else {
    return
}
let duration = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
```

While it might be tempting to use simple modular maths to calculate the format, I'd avoid it, it becomes error prone the larger the interval becomes.

Instead, I'd make use `DateComponentsFormatter`

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
formatter.allowedUnits = [ .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

let durationFormat = formatter.string(from: duration)
```

For more information, have a look at [Formatting a Duration with NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://crunchybagel.com/formatting-a-duration-with-nsdatecomponentsformatter/) - while it's a little out of date, it can provide some insights into how the API works

## Playground

Because these things can be a little complicated, I tend to like to use Playground to test some basic ideas, so the following...

```
let startTime = Date()
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 2.0)
let duration = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
formatter.allowedUnits = [ .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

formatter.string(from: duration)
```

Will eventually display `2s` (I know, thrilling, but it provides the seeds of the idea ;))

Comment: Oh, awesome thanks! I'll try this when I get home, thanks for the quick response, I'm new to using swift so this was a massive help!